# checkit does not throw an error when using async version

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

Using the example from the [GitHub repository for checkit](https://github.com/tgriesser/checkit) with an invalid body, when I run it on Node.js 6.2.2 using the async version, it doesn't throw an error (or at least, it isn't catched - thus no console output):

```
var checkit = new Checkit({
  firstName: 'required',
  lastName: 'required',
  email: ['required', 'email']
});

var body = {
  firstName: 'Tim',
  lastName: 'Griesser',
  githubUsername: 'tgriesser'
};

checkit.run(body).then(function(validated) {
  console.log(validated);
}).catch(Checkit.Error, function(err) {
  console.log(err.toJSON());
})
```

When running the tests from the repository, all tests are green (which contain tests for invalid objects passed to `checkit.run()`.

When running the sample using a valid body, everything is ok. 
It's just the Error path that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
var checkit = new Checkit({
  firstName: 'required',
  lastName: 'required',
  email: ['required', 'email']
});

var body = {
  firstName: 'Tim',
  lastName: 'Griesser',
  githubUsername: 'tgriesser'
};

checkit.run(body).then(function (validated) {
  console.log(validated);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err.toJSON());
});
```

The difference is in the `catch()` statement:

Sample from website: `.catch(Checkit.Error, function(err) {})`

Tests / working solution: `.catch(function(err) {})`

Result as expected:
`{ email: [ 'The email is required' ] }`